# Chrome DevTools: jump from XHR network request, to the code that made it

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug a REST API and see how it's used from very complex client code. After I identify the AJAX request in the Network tab, how can I go to the code that created it?

[image]

Is this [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650466/how-to-retrieve-the-initiator-of-a-request-when-extending-chrome-devtool)?

Comment: Um, how about the XHR log line in the console with the same path?

Comment: I don't think you can do this after the XHR request. The only thing you can do is set an XHR breakpoint, which will fire when the XHR is sent.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

See the "Initiator" column in the network tab. It tells you which code initiated the AJAX call.   You will also get a tooltip with a full stack trace.

[image: Chrome DevTools Network Tab Initiator Stack Trace]

Comment: Duh. Thanks! I took the liberty to add an even more obvious screenshot.

Comment: If you use a library like jQuery or Angular to help you make the call, is there a way to see the source code that called the helper functions?

Comment: @Atav32: you can just go through the call stack

Comment: What if the initiator is "Other"?

Answer (score 13):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment so I'm replying to:

> If you use a library like jQuery or Angular to help you make the call, is >there a way to see the source code that called the helper functions? – >Atav32 Mar 14 at 1:01

If you want to find "real" method call then add breakpoint in line suggested by "Initiator" column and hit "Step out of current function (Shift+F11)" till you reach code you want to.

Cheers!