# Programmatically get web request initiator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, google-chrome-devtools, casperjs, selenium-chromedriver

The Chrome Dev Tools network tab has an initiator column that will show you exactly what code initiated the network request.

[image: network tab of chrome dev tools]

I'd like to be able to get network request initiator information programmatically, so I could run a script with a `url` and `request search string` argument, and it would return details about where every request with a url matching `request search string` came from on the page at `url`. So given the arguments `www.stackoverflow.com` and `google` the output might look something like this (showing requesting url, line number, and requested url):

```
/   19  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
/   4291    http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

I looked into PhantomJS, but its `onResourceRequested` callback doesn't provide any initiator information, or context from which it can be derived, according to the documentation: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html

Is it possible to do with with PhantomJS at all, or some other tool or service such as selenium?

**UPDATE**

From the comments and answers so far it seems as though this isn't currently supported by Phantom, Selenium or anything else. So here's an alternative approach that might work: Load the page, and all of the assets, and then find any occurrences of `request search string` in all of the files. How could I do that?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650466/how-to-retrieve-the-initiator-of-a-request-when-extending-chrome-devtool. I doubt you can get the initiators with selenium since, for starters, both webdriver and chrome developer tools are chrome debuggers and cannot be running at the same time: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing..

Comment: `window.performance.getEntries()` has the [`initiatorType`](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/#widl-PerformanceResourceTiming-initiatorType) for every entry, but no more than that and it's not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You should [file a feature request](http://crbug.com/new) in the issue tracker against the DevTools. The initiator information is not exported in the HAR, so getting it out of there isn't going to work. As far as I know, no existing API allows for this either.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to implement a solution that uses PhantomJS to get all of the URLs loaded by a page, and then use a combination of xargs, curl and grep to find the search string at those URLs.

The first piece is this PhantomJS script, which simply outputs every URL requested by a page:

```
system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceRequested= function(req) {
    console.log(req.url);
};

page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {
    phantom.exit(1);
});
```

Here it is in action:

```
$ phantomjs urls.js http://www.stackoverflow.com | head -n6
http://www.stackoverflow.com/
http://stackoverflow.com/
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=06bb9dbfaca7
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=af4b547e0e9f
http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=d09c08f3cb07
```

For my problem I'm not interested in images, and those can be fitlered out by adding the phantomjs arg `--load-images=no`.

The second piece is taking all of the URLs and searching them. It's not enough to just output the match, I also need the context around which URL was matched, and ideally which line number too. Here's how to do that:

```
$ cat urls | xargs -I% sh -c "curl -s % | grep -E -n -o '(.{0,30})SEARCH_TERM(.{0,30})' | sed 's#^#% #'"
```

We can wrap this all up in a little script, where we'll pipe the output back through grep to get color highlighting on the search string:

```
#!/bin/bash
phantomjs --load-images=no urls.js $1 | xargs -I% sh -c "curl -s % | grep -E -n -o '(.{0,30})$2(.{0,30})' | sed 's#^#% #' | grep $2 --color=always"
```

We can then use it to search for any term on any site. Here we're looking for adzerk.net on stackoverflow.com:

[image]

So you can see that the adzerk.net request gets initiated somewhere around line 4158 of the main stackoverflow page. It's not a perfect solution because the invocation might be somewhere completely different from where the URL is defined, but it's probably a close, and certainly a good point to start tracking down the exact invocation site.

There might be a better way to search the contents of each URL. It doesn't look like PhantonJS's [onResourceReceived](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) handler currently exposes the resource content, but there is [ongoing work to address that](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10158), and once that's available all of this will be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome's [debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) from a process external to Chrome or use the [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API in a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) (see [How to retrieve the Initiator of a request when extending Chrome DevTool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650466/how-to-retrieve-the-initiator-of-a-request-when-extending-chrome-devtool)).

Comment: The answer you've linked to says it's not possible.

Comment: @BenDowling, it says that when using a [Chrome DevTools Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) and the exposed data through HAR that it isn't possible but it is possible through the debugger API. I suggest [sniffing the protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#sniffing-the-protocol) as described under [Debugging over the wire](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#remote) to find the necessary APIs you will need to get network details, etc. and then implementing a chrome extension to capture & expose the data you want.

Comment: I want to do this in a headless env. Would a chrome extension work for that? I think my suggested approach of just gripping all resources for the search string is looking like the simplest way to go.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "grepping". How will you get the directory of all of the sources? I suspect you'll need to use a Chrome extension for that (or a DevTools extension).

Comment: Yeah, autocorrect! :) using phantomjs. I'll write it up as an answer if nobody beats me to it

Comment: But yes, Chrome extensions will run regardless of whether or not the browser is running in a headless environment or not and can execute scripts in the background (e.g. attach to the debugger on tab creation, etc.).